# let $A,B$ matrices $n \times n$ and $A \ne B , AB=0$ and $A\ne 0 , B\ne0$ prove $\left|A\right|^2+\left|B\right|^2=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, solution-verification

**let $A,B$ matrices $n \times n$ such that $A \ne B $ and $AB=0$ and $A\ne 0 , B\ne0$ prove $\left|A\right|^2+\left|B\right|^2=0$**

My attempt:

$$AB=0 \implies \det(AB)=0 \implies \det(A)*\det(B)=0 \iff $$
$$|B|=0\qquad\text{or}\qquad |A|=0\qquad\text{or}\qquad|A|=|B|=0.$$

if $|A|=0 , |B| \ne0$ then $B^{-1}$ exist $\implies ABB^{-1}=0 \implies A=0 \implies$contradiction

if $|B|=0 , |A| \ne0$ same as before

and if $|B|=0 , |A| =0$ then also $\left|A\right|^2+\left|B\right|^2=0$

My question is does this correct what I did and if not where did I did wrong ?

thanks

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: My only comment is that you did not include "$A\ne 0$, $B\ne 0$" in the title.

Comment: My bad I"ll edit it